# Excel date changed (month and day swapped) after reading and writing with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting

I wrote two lines of simple VBA codes to read from and write a date to a cell, but unexpectedly the month and day swapped after the run. The steps are:

1. Enter a date "1/11/2017" in the cell A1. The date is now displayed as "01/11/2017".
2. Run the following lines of code:

   ```
   Dim s As String
   s = Cells(1, 1).value
   Cells(2, 1).value = s
   ```
3. The cell B1 now displays "11/01/2017" with the month and day swapped.

My short date format setting in Region in Windows is "dd/MM/yyyy" so the string s stores the value "01/11/2017". However, when writing to the cell, Excel implicitly converts the string s to a date assuming "mm/dd/yyyy" without following the date format setting in Region. I tried to use different short date format settings but that does not change the way Excel converts the string.

So my question is: what could explain the swapping of the day and month? What controls how Excel reads the date string and write to the cell?

Comment: Change `Dim s As String` to `Dim s As Date`

Comment: OR change `Cells(2, 1).value = s` to `Cells(2, 1).Value = DateValue(s)`

Comment: Thanks, I agree this is one of the workarounds since in the first method, there is no conversion to/from string so there is no ambiguity, and in the second method, DateValue checks the short date format settings before doing the conversion. But I still want to know why Excel behaves like that when writing a string directly into a cell because one may not always remember to take your approaches when doing so and I want to avoid that.

Comment: This is not a workaround... I am already typing an answer. gimme few minutes :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim s As String
s = Cells(1, 1).Value
```

`s = Cells(1, 1).value` will store the `value` of the cell in a `String`. Not what it shows in the cell.

For example

If your cell has `11/1/2017` but is formatted to show `01/11/17` then `s` will store `11/1/2017`. This is not a date. It is a `String`. If you do not believe me then try this

```
Dim s As String
s = Cells(1, 1).Value
Debug.Print s + 1 '<~~ You will get a Type Mismatch error
```

Now try this

```
Dim s As Date
s = Cells(1, 1).Value
Debug.Print s + 1 '<~~ You will get a proper date
```

**==>** When you are trying to store a `String` which contains a date to a cell which has `General` format then Excel will convert the string to date in a format what it feels is best (based on regional settings). And this is what is happening in your case.

**Resolution**:

`1` Declare a `Date` variable and then store the value in that. Ex: `Dim s As Date`

OR

`2` Convert the string to a date and then store it. Excel will not change it. And that is what `DateValue(s)` does.

**Some Testing**

Let's take these 3 scenarios

```
Sub SampleA()
    Dim s As Date
    s = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Cells(2, 1).Value = s
End Sub

Sub SampleB()
    Dim s As String
    s = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Cells(2, 1).Value = DateValue(s)
End Sub

Sub SampleC() '<~~ As Suggested in the other answer
    Dim s As String

    s = Cells(1, 1).Value

    Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Cells(2, 1).Value = s
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understand that your methods work, and I could think of using `CDate` as well which checks the short date setting in Region to convert a string to a date. But what I am interested in is based on what Excel makes the implicit conversion. And you mentioned "in a format what it feels is best (based on regional settings)" - can you clarify which field in the Region setting Excel looks at?